# Content goes beyond the viewport vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm facing a problem which i can't explain on text so i;m attaching a video link to help you understand.
I have used a sidebar, header and the 2 flex items for the columns.
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/7825218?key=a98fd698c6f92d18c81833ab5b653e02

Comment: Please include an [example]. The screen recording is helpful to tell us the exact problem, but without code, there is no telling what the solution could be.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.